# Just want to change directory from c: to e: using PowerShell on Windows 7

Tags: powershell

The following command "Set-Location" works directly from the PowerShell command prompt:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-Location E:
PS E:\>
```

But running as -Command argument to Powershell.exe:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> powershell -Command {Set-Location E:}
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

The drive doesn't change.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using powershell.exe as I want to be able to run the commands from a file e.g. script.bat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But of course it works try :

```
powershell -Command {Set-Location E:; Get-ChildItem}
```

And you will see the content of E:.

The explanation is that you create a new process in which you change to drive E:, then the process end and you return where you were.

Comment: Tried: powershell -Command {Set-Location E:/mouth/project/resmprdres/resmprdrest/resmprdrest;./goSelenium;} but didn't seem to do anything :-( if I type the respective commands in at the powershell prompt I get required response i.e. PS >: Set-Location.. and then PS > ./goSelenium

Comment: By the way (re your reply) i just get: ********************************************************************C:\Users\ryanki1>powershell -Command {Set-Location E:;Get-ChildItem}
Set-Location E:; Get-ChildItem
PS C:\Users\ryanki1>

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand tour last comment.

Comment: ok if i rename my .bat file to .ps1 then i see a directory listing of E:\ as you predicted :-)

Comment: Ok so now if i say -- PS> start-job ./goResmprdres.ps1 i get a background job running. So long as i use this powershell session (as Duncan suggested) for further work e.g. running some end to end tests, then everthing is looking rosey. Thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Every process has it's own current drive and directory. When you run a sub-process any changes to the current location apply only to that process (and any other processes it starts *after* it changed the location). Your original process continue to use the location it had when it started the sub-process.

The same applies to environment variables: a process can influence the environment for any children it starts before it starts them, but there is no way for it to change its parent process's environment (nor to modify any child process's environment after the child has been started).